# Mediawiki - the edit module requires a post request

Tags: powershell, curl, mediawiki-api

I tried to call the below mediawiki api urls in browser. But it shows error messages like, The login module requires a POST request and The edit module requires a POST request. What should I give additionally with URL ? Also how can I call this from cURL or from powershell ?

```
http://localhost/mediawiki/api.php?action=login&lgname=admin&lgpassword=1234

http://localhost/mediawiki/api.phpname=admin&password=1234&action=edit&title=Test&
summary=test%20summary&text=article%20content&token=%2B%5C
```

Comment: Maybe you should read about what [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) actually is.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do a post request straight from the browser without writing your own form/html page or using some sort of plugin/add-on like [Advanced Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client-appl/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/reviews?hl=en-US&utm_source=ARC&utm_medium=InsideApplication&utm_campaign=About) Google Chrome Extension.

If you are using PowerShell v3.0 or above, you can do a post request using [Invoke-RestMethod](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849971%28v=wps.620%29.aspx) like so:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "http://localhost/yada.php?yadayada" -Body @{FormField1Name="FormField1Value";FormField2Name="FormField2Value"
```

Read over the documentation for Invoke-RestMethod, and you will find it can meet your needs.